# create a new drop down based on another drop down in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Here is my requirement.

List item

1. I have a couple of dropdowns A and B
2. I have a javascript key-value variable created:
3. var keyvalue={"key1":["value1","value2"],"key2":["value2","value4"]}
4. I am populating the keys in dropdown A, on selecting this dropdown, i am populating the corresponding values (froom the keyvalue variable) into the drop down B

Here is the sample code i a using :[image]

The problem is even if i select a different option in dropdown A, the corresponding old option is present in the new drop down,i.e, new values are appended, rather than creating a new drop down
Any help is appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: say first i am selecting key1 in dropdown A, so value1 and value2 are populated in the dropdown B, if i select key2, then value3 and value4 are appended to the already existing values.

Comment: It's much better to put the code with 4 indents `    ` than to put an image of the code that cannot be easily copied here. You want to `.remove()` the children first, `.replaceWith()` or `.html()` for jquery.

Comment: since i was running short of time,instead of formating the code,thought pasting the image ,thanks a lot Francisco

Comment: One thing to point out: you're only using jQuery for a single .ready() statement, but with your script at the end of the `body`, you can actually remove lines, "$( document ).ready(function() {" and it's closing, "})". Then you'll be running completely native :) and can drop some dead weight and remove your jQuery `<script>` reference all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all options before populating. Add this directly right after your `var quantity` statement.

```
while (selectvalue.options.length > 0) {
    selectvalue.remove();
}
```

---

Also, as mentioned by @francisco-presencia, you should lose the `onchange` in the HTML and instead use an event listener within your script.

Comment: That will only work on page load, not every time the drop down is changed. Besides, you can just do `selectvalue.remove();`, without the 0.

Comment: ah, yep, i said to put it in the wrong place. Updating my post. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you go the [separation of concerns route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript). That means deleting the `onclick=""` event, and instead doing:

```
$('#key').change(function(){
  $('#value').remove();
  // Do the rest of the logic of retrievevalue() here.
  });
```

Comment: thanks a lot franciso,i changed my code accoriding to what you said,a with a slight correction, i added :$('#key').change(function(){
  $('#value option').remove();
  // Do the rest of the logic of retrievevalue() here.
  });  It was throwing error otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You should use `empty()` to remove the old options before appending the new.

You can see it on my sample Fiddle:

[JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yby42/)

```
$('#select2').empty().append(Weapons);
```